# Getting selected value from Listbox into parent in App()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am creating a DropDown component, and I copy and paste the code from the [Tailwind UI Simple Selector](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/select-menus) into a file called `DropDown.tsx`

```
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon, ChevronUpDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'

const people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Wade Cooper' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Arlene Mccoy' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Devon Webb' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Tom Cook' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Tanya Fox' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Hellen Schmidt' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Caroline Schultz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Mason Heaney' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Claudie Smitham' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Emil Schaefer' },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function DropDown() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[3])

  return (
    <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <Listbox.Label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Assigned to</Listbox.Label>
          <div className="relative mt-1">
            <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
              <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
              <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
                <ChevronUpDownIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
              </span>
            </Listbox.Button>

            <Transition
              show={open}
              as={Fragment}
              leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <Listbox.Options className="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
                {people.map((person) => (
                  <Listbox.Option
                    key={person.id}
                    className={({ active }) =>
                      classNames(
                        active ? 'text-white bg-indigo-600' : 'text-gray-900',
                        'relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9'
                      )
                    }
                    value={person}
                  >
                    {({ selected, active }) => (
                      <>
                        <span className={classNames(selected ? 'font-semibold' : 'font-normal', 'block truncate')}>
                          {person.name}
                        </span>

                        {selected ? (
                          <span
                            className={classNames(
                              active ? 'text-white' : 'text-indigo-600',
                              'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4'
                            )}
                          >
                            <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                          </span>
                        ) : null}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Listbox.Option>
                ))}
              </Listbox.Options>
            </Transition>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </Listbox>
  )
}
```

Then I import that component into my `App.tsx` via `import DropDown from "./DropDown";` and render it with `<DropDown />`

All works fine and renders.

But I can do what I want, I don't get the value of `selected` in `DropDown.tsx` into `App.tsx`.

I tried several approaches adding properties to the Dropdown or using `onChange` or `onClick`. Maybe I need to emit an event on the component?

I want that `onChange` in `App.tsx` calls a function with the value `selected`.

```
  const handleSelectChange = async (exampleChange: any) => {
    const value = exampleChange;
    console.log("adad")
    // set the current example to the selected one
    setExample(value)

    // retrieve the example data and update the inputs and code
    const example_code = await getExample(value)
    setInputs(await example_code[0])
    setCode(await example_code[1])    

    // reset the output
    setOutput(emptyOutput)
  }
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback prop into the Dropdown component that will be invoked on the Listbox's onChange event.

```
export default function DropDown({ onChange }) {
     const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[3])
     const handleOnChange = (selected) => {
          onChange(selected);
          setSelected(selected);
     }
     ...
     return (
        <Listbox value={selected} onChange={handleOnChange}>
           ...
        </Listbox>
     )
}
```

Then you can pass the handleSelectChange function from App into the Dropdown

```
...
   <Dropdown onChange={handleSelectChange} />
...
```

While this would work, you can also consider moving the useState hook into App and passing only the state and state setters into the Dropdown. This is a common practice in React and is commonly called "lifting the state up".